# After File Download Refresh or Redirect to the same page in c#

Tags: c#, meta-tags, page-refresh, response.redirect, response.addheader

Please Help me how to Refresh or Redirect to the same page after downloading a file using c# code Please find the code I am using in c#.

I am used 
Below code also some time to check but not worked. Please give me the solution to refresh a page after file download, Because of i am lossing some mutipledropdownlist css is not working properly.

```
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
 Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3; url=" + url + "");
```

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onload", "javascript:location.reload(true);", true);
```

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta meta = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "Refresh";
meta.Content = "5;url=TCO.aspx";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + myfile.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myfile.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/x-mspowerpoint";
Response.WriteFile(myfile.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: You are sending the file as the response to the request. You can't also send any other kind of response at the same time.

Comment: Please give me any other way to refresh a page.@ADyson

Comment: I'm not aware of any such way. Perhaps others will have a suggestion to work around it